# Como faço um IF e desabilito um campo usando script

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

gostaria de uma ajuda,
queria fazer um IF para desabilitar ou habilitar um campo que venha com o valor 1 ou 0.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnProduto").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Selecionar",
      data: { id_produto: $("#ListaProdutos").val() },
      success: function (mensagem) {
        //alert(mensaje);
        //$("#idproducto").val(mensaje.Nombre);
        $(mensagem).each(function (index, item) {
          //recibir datos json
          $("#descricao").val(item.descricao),
          $("#id_produto").val(item.id_produto)
          $("#pvenda").val(item.pvenda)
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

meu campo que quero bloquear ou desbloquear é o `$("#pvenda").val(item.pvenda)`, essa campo vai me retorna apenas 2 valores, 1 ou 0, caso seja 0 eu quero desabilitar o campo para o usuário não edite ele, e se for 1 eu quero que o campo fique habilitado para o usuário informa o valor que desejar.
Desde já agradeço !!

Comment: Alysson vocÊ está recebendo os valores certinho no ajax?

Comment: O estranho é você receber de  `$("#pvenda").val(item.pvenda)`, um JSON não oferece dados dessa maneira.

Comment: to sim @LeonardoBonetti, ta trazendo os valor certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade `disabled` para isso, assim:

```
if ( $("#pvenda").val(item.pvenda).val() == 0 )
{
   $("#pvenda").val(item.pvenda).prop("disabled", true)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo !!!!!